# Trouble with creating web pages

Tags: javascript, html, page-refresh

I'm having trouble with creating a web page with following features:

- When users visit my page, their address bar will display ONLY URLs having no accompanied ID such as http://127.0.0.1/client
- Whenever they REFRESH the page, real requested URLs will be attached with IDs. For example: http://127.0.0.1/client?id=3

Previously, I tried to use hidden input tags, but it's fruitless. Any idea?

My mark up is below

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1,url=/client'>
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:setTimeout('location.reload(true);',0);">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="3" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What determines the id value?

Comment: Do you really mean "refresh", or post?

Answer (score 0):

You can hijack page refresh with something that POSTs to your page.

Comment: Could you explain it in detail?

Answer (score 0):

You could use pushState to change the url on load like:

```
function updateURL (){
    window.history.pushState(null, null, "?id=3")
}

window.onload=updateURL;
```

You could also accomplish something similar using location.hash as pushState is not supported on some old browsers.